# How to adjust window size using primeng ngx-print feature in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have used primengs ngx-print feature for printing the pages.
but the problem is that it working properly in chrome but in IE11 and mozilla the preview window size is very small.I have to adjust the window size using ngx-print.

any one happen to know anything about it?

Comment: Feel free to share the code and issue and expected result!

Comment: thanks @ Prashant Pimpale.i customized the directive got worked.

Comment: ok..or else if the problem still exists then share the code

Comment: Can someone help with this question's answer? I am facing the same issue.